# Perform Firestore queries in the GCP console?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

During testing I want to perform quick Firestore queries such as below:

```
let doc = db.doc('collection/document/');
doc.get()
```

Is there a console I can run these Admin SDK functions directly?

At the moment I'm having to write testing functions in my Cloud Functions index.js or my Android code and then reinstall the app, but that's not very efficient...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "breadcrumb" like editable control at the top of the Firestore module in the Firebase console:

[image]

By hovering over the home icon, you will see a pencil icon which allows you to switch the breadcrumb to edit mode and enter the desired path (collection or document path).

The above image shows a non existing path but with an existing one you will see either the collection or a specific document.